# Shared Mailboxes on Outlook Web Access

Tags: outlook-web-access, shared-mailbox

Simple question really. When logging on to a shared mailbox via OWA

(https://orgname.com/owa/mailbox@domain.com)

As when the log on page appears for this it asks for the username and password of a person with access to this shared mailbox, I was wondering if there was an option to include something in the URL which would auto-populate the username field when the log on page loads?

Something like (i know this won't work, but to give you a clearer idea of what I'm after);

https://orgname.com/owa/mailbox@domain.com&username=user1

If it's not possible, so be it, but if it is, it would make things easier, is all.